# Android Studio deleted R file

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I have a problem. After improper closing (technical problems) of my project, `R.java` was deleted. Is it an Android Studio or Gradle problem? Is there some way to regenerate the `R` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R.java` will generate automatic and if its not regenerated , maybe its an error inside your Resources

Comment: where is this folder in your project studio android?

Answer (score 2):

Also, whenever you will have issues with Android Studio, that something stopped working, after crash/technical issues - you can always do:
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Answer (score 1):

Your R file will generate by itself and if it does not get generated there may be some problem with the things you have imported in your project such as pictures (Images ) in the drawable and etc. remove the faulty image and then build gradle , your R file will regenerate after that .

Hope This Helps :)